# Number of surjections from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ to $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Where $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

My book says it's:

1. Select a two-element subset of $A$.
2. Assign images without repetition to the two-element subset and the four
   remaining individual elements of $A$.

This shows that the total number of surjections from $A$ to $B$ is $C(6, 2)5! = 1800$.

I'm confused at why it's multiplied by $5!$ and not by $4!$. Also in part 2, when we assign images, do they mean images in $B$?

Comment: There are $5$ objects, not $4$.  One object is the double, but that doesn't change anything,

Comment: I thought since we have a subset of 2, we multiply by 4! since there are 4 elements left in A.

Comment: It's not a question of what's left in $A$.  Having paired, say, $1,2$ we now need to count the surjections of $\{P,3,4,5,6\}$ onto $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, where $P$ denotes the pair $(1,2)$.  There are clearly $5!$ such surjections.

Comment: " I thought ..., we multiply by 4! since there are 4 elements left in A." But you haven't chosen which of the 5 elements that subset of 2 map to.  Would it make more sense if we said the (number of ways to chose the two that aren't distinct)(choices for that pair)(choices for what is left) $={6\choose 2}*5*4! $? That's actually the same thing as (number of ways to chose the two that aren't distinct)(number of choices for the four distinct and the pair)$={6\choose 2}*5! $.

Answer (score 4):

How many ways can $A$ be partitioned into $5$ blocks?

Answer: $\binom{6}{2} = 15$

Given any $5\text{-block}$ partition of $A$, in how many ways can the blocks be bijectively 
assigned to the $5$ element set $B$?

Answer: $5! =120$

How many surjective functions from $A$ onto $B$ are there?

Answer: $15 \times 120 = 1800$

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way:

There is a pair of terms that get mapped to the same element.  Call that pair $\alpha $.  There are four terms remaining.  Call them $\beta,\gamma,\delta$ and $\epsilon $.

There are ${6\choose 2} $ possible pairs that can be $\alpha $.

And we must map $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon $ to $a,b,c,d,e $.  There is $5! $ ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

(i). Select  a $2$-member  $A_1\subset A.$ There are $\binom {6}{2}$ ways to do this. Select a $1$-member  $B_1\subset B.$ There are $\binom {5}{1}$ ways to do this. There are $\binom {6}{2}\binom {5}{1}$ such pairs $(A_1,B_1)$ and for each pair  there is a set $F(A_1,B_1)$ of $4!$ surjections $f:A\to B$ such that $\{f(x):x\in A_1\}=B_1.$

And if $(A_1, B_1)\ne (A'_1, B'_1)$ then the sets $F(A_1,B_1), F(A'_1,B'_1)$ are disjoint.

So there are at least $\binom {6}{2}\binom {5}{1}4!=(15)(5)(4!)=(15)(5!)=1800$ surjections.

(ii). Every surjection $f:A\to B$ belongs to some $F(A_1,B_1)$ so there are at most $1800$ surjections.

In other words: (i) we didn't count any $f$ more than once, and (ii) we didn't fail to count any $f$.

Remark. The "mysterious" $5!$ came from two sources: The product of the number $\binom {5}{1}$  of $B_1$'s and the number $4$!  of bijections from a $4$-member set to another.